# Want text to be vertically & horizontally centered within an <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an <a> element (links to Javascript) but I'm designing it as a button.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

The CSS:

```
#closebtn {
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 100px;
    right: 45px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#closebtn:hover {
    background-color: #5c564f;
    color: #FFF6EA;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF6EA;
}
```

Right now I've got it centered horizontally with `text-align`, but it's still stuck to the top of the circle. Any way to get the X to be centered in the dead middle of the circular "button"?

I've tried justify-element, but I guess what's stumping me is that I'm ultimately working with <a> and not <button> or <div>. There's probably a simple solution - I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Since the alignment is affected by font size (the "x" text) it's very hard to use a normal alignment method like flexbox. You can though, wrap the text in a span and position that with CSS since your anchor element is already using absolute positioning. It's a quick and dirty way, but that's all I can think of

Answer (score 0):

You may set it's `display` as `flex`, and then set `align-items` and `justify-content` to `center`. This will make the X in center.

However as stated by @konekoya, the alignment is affected by the font size, so the X will not be like 100% in the dead middle (except if you adjust the font size).

```css
#closebtn {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 100px;
    right: 45px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#closebtn:hover {
    background-color: #5c564f;
    color: #FFF6EA;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF6EA;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```